# BPEL apache ODe deploy

Tags: bpel, apache-ode

Could anyone point me how to deploy a BPEL in Apache Ode from java? Is there any convenient way to  create the deploy.xml file and then deploy it? Creating it with plain XML and then saving to the process directory doesn't look nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the deployment you can use the deployment API provided via Web service or the hot deployment (by copying the deployable to the `processes` directory).

There is no generator for the deploy.xml, however, the schema is straight-forward. ODE has a XMLBeans-based java object model in the `bpel-schemas` module (see `org.apache.ode.bpel.dd.DeployDocument`). The Eclipse BPEL designer also contains a EMF-based metamodel for the same schema and tries to guess some smart defaults based on the WSDLs used.

Comment: Can you please tell me exactly what has to be copied to `processes` directory for hot deployment?